# Unable to play dvd's in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dvd

This appears to be quite a common problem, but I cannot get DVD's to play on Trusty Tahr. I have VLC, and per the online forums I installed the following

libdvdread4
libdvdcss
ubuntu restricted packages

I also installed regionset and that didn't work either as it won't recognize that there is a disc in the drive, although VLC can see (just not play it)

Other video seems to be fine, as I can stream and even download and play

Comment: did you also do: `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` as on: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Comment: Have you tried other DVDs, and can it be opened in file manager?